# Why won't my system boot off of a partition that I just transferred the Ubuntu install image to using the dd command?

Tags: boot, partitioning, hard-drive, dd

I have a drive that I would like to install Linux onto, for eventual use on another machine.  I want to bring the Ubuntu installer image onto a 20GB partition, and then boot into that.

When I boot onto that partition, I will install the Ubuntu system onto one of the remaining ~500GB partitions of the same hard disk drive.

---

Using the `lsblk` command, you can see my current system drive and partition `sda1`, as well as the 1TB `sdb` drive that will be the destination system.

```
mono@mono-Studio-XPS-9100:~$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 111.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0 103.8G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0     8G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb      8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0 457.8G  0 part 
├─sdb2   8:18   0 454.2G  0 part 
└─sdb3   8:19   0  19.5G  0 part 
mono@mono-Studio-XPS-9100:~$
```

`sbd3` is the partition of interest onto which I put the Ubuntu install image.

```
sudo dd if = 'ubuntukylin-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso' of=/dev/sdb3
```

After executing this dd command, the 20GB sdb3 partition became unmounted.  When I rebooted my computer, physically unplugging the sda hard drive, I got a black cursor instead of booting into Linux.

---

Do I need to do something further?

When I physically re-plugged in the original hard drive and rebooted into my original linux system, the 20GB partition mounted, and inside I have what appears to be the Ubuntu-Kylin 14.04 LTS amd64 system.

UPDATE:
I realized that in gparted I could right click the sdab3 partition and change the flags.  I selected bootable.

[image]
[image]

Now instead of booting to a cursor, it says `isolinux.bin missing or corrupt.  Reboot and select proper Boot device or Insert Boot Media ...'

Comment: That seems like it's a corrupted file... Try re-downloading Kylin. Also, why can't you just use a USB drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this Link ([Ubuntu Live-USB Creation](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu)) can help you. It worked fine for me, because I never got it to work manually just with dd, the other tools worked for me just fine :)